# How print array value which stored in another array

Tags: php, arrays

**`$res`** stores result query and function output.

When I write

```
print_r($res);
```

then output is :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [@out] => 50 [0] => 112 ) )
```

Now, I want to print values **`112`** and **`50`**.
And I want to store that value in another variable.

Comment: `$var1 = $res[0][0];`

`$var2 = $res[0]['@out'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ..

1st [0] is the index number and '@out' is ID .

That type of result got only on stored procedures...

$val = $res[0]['@out'];
$val2 = $res[0]['0'];

echo $val;   // to print value 50

echo $val2;   // to print value 112

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
echo $res[0]['@out'];
echo $res[0]['0'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/* To store in other variables */  
$out_value = $res[ 0 ][ '@out' ];  
$zero_indexed_value = $res[ 0 ][ '0' ];  

/* To print */  
print_r( $out_value );  
print_r( $zero_indexed_value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is [multidimensiona](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp)l array.so for storing values in to another variable and if you know the keys of the array use this

```
$value1 = $res[0]['@out'];
$value2 = $res[0]['0'];
```

to print try this

```
echo $value1;

echo $value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the array values by keys like the following.

```
/* Your array */
$res = array(
   "0" => array(
      "@out" => "50",
      "0" => "112"
   )
);

/* Returns 50 */
echo $res['0']['@out'];

/* Returns 112 */
echo $res['0']['0'];
```